# is it possible to use sendredirect() to redirect to a page in a sub directory

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to a jsp page from my servlet. The redirect works when I place my page directly in the `WebContent` folder, but I need to place it in a sub-folder ie; `WebContent/Web-INF/view`

following does not work :

```
resp.sendRedirect(resp.encodeRedirectURL("WEB-INF/view/welcome.jsp"));
```

while using request dispatcher works...

wondering if there is a way to use `sendRedirect()` for pages in sub-folders ?

Location of my servlet is : Java Resources/src/

Answer (score 4):

You can't redirect to resources inside `WEB-INF`. All resources in that directory are non-visible to the browser, by design.

Either keep the JSP outside of `WEB-INF`, or add a servlet which forwards to the JSP, and redirect to the servlet instead.

> I need to place it in a sub-folder

This is often good practice, but why do you *need* to do this?

Comment: thanks for the reply... i'm placing it in the sub folders just to make sure no one can access it without going through the authentication process ie by directly typing in the URL

Comment: For the authentication part you normally use a [servlet filter](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info), or [container managed authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) of course.